# Filter non-alphabetic characters out of string in shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, scripting

Very simple question but can't seem to find a simple answer...

I am writing a bash script which needs to remove all non-alphabetic and non-numeric characters. Eg. I want...

```
INPUT_STRING="ABC# .1-2-3"

OUTPUT_STRING= # some form of processing on $INPUT_STRING #

echo $OUTPUT_STRING
ABC123
```

I realize that this would be best solved using regex, but not sure how to use this effectively in the script.

All help greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `sed` to strip all chars that are not `a-z`, `A-Z` or `0-9`:

```
$ echo "ABC# .1-2-3" | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g'
ABC123
```

So in your case,

```
$ INPUT_STRING="ABC# .1-2-3"
$ OUTPUT_STRING=$(echo $INPUT_STRING | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g')
$ echo $OUTPUT_STRING
ABC123
```

Answer (score 10):

```
$ INPUT_STRING="ABC# .1-2-3"
$ printf '%s\n' "${INPUT_STRING//[![:alnum:]]}"
ABC123
```

Comment: Or rather, `OUTPUT_STRING="${INPUT_STRING//[![:alnum:]]}"`

Comment: Thanks, I haven't noticed that @Rich wanted to store the modified value in a variable. I would use `OUTPUT_STRING=${INPUT_STRING//[![:alnum:]]}` though, the right side of the assignment statement is not subject to shell word/field splitting, so the quotes are redundant.

Comment: It saddens my heart to see yet another pure BASH solution lose out to a lazy forking sed/awk/perl P.O.S.

Comment: I just played with this solution and find it really useful. Thanks!
`read MYNUMBER && echo "${MYNUMBER//[![:digit:]]}"`